# Failed to save list of maps content to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, go, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-nested

i am trying to save list of maps contents to elastic search(as nested type)and it is failing. sample code is below 
import (
    "fmt"
)

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    var List_CounterData []interface{}
    List_Counterdata = map[string]interface{}{}
    err := savekpi(List_Counterdata)
    if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error in save")
    }   
}

func saveKpi(kpi interface{}) error {
    put1, err := elasticSearchClient.Index().
        Index(KpiIndex).
        Type(KpiDocType).
        Id("1001").
        BodyJson(kpi).
        Do(elasticSearchContext)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to store Kpi , %v", err.Error())
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("Indexed  %s to index %s, type %s\n", put1.Id, put1.Index, put1.Type)
    return err
}
```

My List_Counterdata sample is below

> List_Counterdata = [map[name: kisha] map[name: kish age: 29]]

When trying to create index, following the error

```
elastic: Error 400 (Bad Request): failed to parse [type=mapper_parsing_exception]
```

Comment: What does your index mapping look like? Are you sure `List_CounterData` has what you expect?  Where are `KpiIndex` and `KpiDocType` defined?

Comment: Hi Please find the declaration 


const RegisterIndex = "register"
const KpiIndex = "kpi"

// Register & Kpi Index doc type
const RegisterDocType = "register"
const KpiDocType = "kpi"

const KpiMapping = `
{
 "mappings": {
  "kpi": {
   "properties": {
    "kpi": {
     "type": "nested" 
    }
   }
  }
 }
}`

Comment: @Cfreak above is the data type declarations